# Haskell cabal: Missing C library

Tags: haskell, cabal

Whe i try to install the Haskell package "call-haskell-from-anything" i get the following error messages:

```
cabal.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: HSrts-ghc8.0.1
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\Manfred\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-2460\call-haskell-from-anything-1.0.1.0'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
call-haskell-from-anything-1.0.1.0 failed during the configure step. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

What is this **HSrts-ghc8.0.1** library and where can i find it on a Windows system?
Or do i have to manually install this library in Windows?

**Edit 1:**

In the meantime i tried the "stack" tool and got a similar error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\Manfred\AppData\Local\Temp\stack4480\call-haskell-from-anything-1.0.1.0\Setup.hs, C:\Users\Manfred\AppData\Local\Temp\stack4480\call-haskell-from-anything-1.0.1.0\.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\setup\Main.o )
    Linking C:\Users\Manfred\AppData\Local\Temp\stack4480\call-haskell-from-anything-1.0.1.0\.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\setup\setup.exe ...
    Configuring call-haskell-from-anything-1.0.1.0...
    Determining GHC version: 7.10.3
    setup.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
    * Missing C library: HSrts-ghc7.10.3
    This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
    provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
    already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
    --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

Comment: It looks to me like it's part of GHC (specifically, the RTS or "runtime system"). What version of GHC are you using?

Comment: I'm using the 8.0.1 32bit version on Windows 10

Comment: OK. So you shouldn't need to *install* anything, you just need to figure out where the DLL is, and convince Cabal to find it. I'm not exactly sure of the answer to either of those parts...

Comment: Background info: https://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/so.xhtml

Comment: This points to a broken setup.  How did you install GHC? How did you install Cabal?

Comment: I installed it exactly like it it is described on this website: https://www.haskell.org/platform/ . I downloaded Windows version and 32Bit minimal.

Comment: I tried it now with "stack" tool, please see my Edit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work on Windows (yet).

`call-haskell-from-anything` seems rely on using a version of GHC that requires `-dynamic` support. From their cabal file:

```
ghc-options: 
   -- For building TemplateHaskell with cabal and -dynamic, we have to disable -dynamic sometimes 
   -no-hs-main -fPIC -shared -dynamic
```

Also `-fPIC` is not a flag that means anything on Windows as windows doesn't use/need Position Independent Code.

`HSrts-ghc8.0.1` is referring to the dynamic version of the GHC runtime which is not currently building on Windows due to https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5987

I am trying to get this done by `8.2.1` which should support dynamic compilation again. But for now, sorry, this package won't work.

Dynamic support may not be needed, so you can try unpacking the project and editing the cabal file, removing `-fPIC` and `-dynamic`.